# Resharper shows all tests as inconclusive and has error "testadapter.dll does not exist on disk"

Tags: visual-studio, nunit, resharper, nunit-3.0

I created a new dot net core unit test project in Visual Studio using Visual Studio 2017. It uses NUnit 3. When I run the tests all of them show as "Inconclusive: Test not run".

Additionally, the Resharper test runner shows an error: "testadapter.dll does not exist on disk".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I needed to install the NUnit3TestAdapter Nuget package.

Looking back, this seems like it should have been obvious to me. I was surprised that searching for the error message did not point towards the solution.

Less obvious was the fact that I had to install the Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk Nuget package.

Comment: That's just the way .NET Core works :) See https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/.NET-Core-and-.NET-Standard

Comment: Damn it, I spent a few hours trying to fix this issue, why didn't I find your post earlier? Thanks Andrew

Comment: Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk is the key here!